# Switching from httpwebrequest to httpclient and I can't figure out how to send my header?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, httpclient

So, this is the code I was using

```
    string URL = "http://www.test.com/posts/.json";
    var getInfo = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);{
    getInfo.Headers["Cookie"] = CookieHeader;
    getInfo.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    using (WebResponse postStream = await getInfo.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(postStream.GetResponseStream());
        string str = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

and I want to switch to httpclient, which I've got working, except it doesn't pass the Cookie information.  I get the information, but just the anonymous information.  Not the information for the user that I'm sending across.  Here is what I currently have.

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.test.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", CookieHeader);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.test.com" + URL);
    string str;
    str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use an `HttpClientHandler`, add your cookies to it and then pass it into the `HttpClient`'s constructor.

An example:

```
    Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.test.com/");
    HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    clientHandler.CookieContainer.Add(baseUri, new Cookie("name", "value"));
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.BaseAddress = baseUri;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.test.com" + URL);
    string str2 = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I found a reference to this same behavior [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/10317), stating that a header named "Cookie" in `DefaultRequestHeaders` is ignored and not sent, but seemingly any other value will work as expected.